# Too many connections error in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database-administration

I am developing an app using C# and MySql (**stored procedure**). After running the app for certain time it shows **Too many connection**. Then I used commands like `SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_connected';` and `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` to debug the problem. It seems each time I run any action on my app, mysql creates new thread and the thread is marked as **Sleep**. Moreover the thread does not close on time. I found one solution i.e setting mysql environment variables as below.

```
 interactive_timeout=180
 wait_timeout=180
```

1. Is this solution have any impact on the app as it automatically kills the connection? What happens if data fetching time from database is a bit long?
2. I am expecting huge traffic about 1000 at a time. So what should be the max connection number in mysql? Will that degrade the mysql performance?

[Note: There is no problem in my app as I have closed every mysql connection]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your note sounds like you actually call `Close` on your connections. Have you thought about `using` blocks? That's way easier than handling all the possible exception scenarios yourself.

Comment: Yes I am using `Close`. I will give it a try if nothing works.

Comment: Calling `Close` manually is prone to errors, because exceptions or normal flow control may bypass your Close call. Commands and Readers can be used with `using` blocks as well, so you don't need to keep an eye on resource management when an exception happens.

Comment: If I have to use `using` then I have to make a lot more change in my application. There are more than 300 places to make changes. So i was looking for a shortcut.

Comment: Well, `using` *is* the shortcut you can use when programmming correct `Close` behaviour manually is too much. You are saying you did 300 places manually and you have problems. Most likely, you made some small mistakes in some of these 300 places. That's only normal, everyone would do that, that's why the `using` construct exists. To help developers make less errors.

Answer (score 1):

I hope below artical will help you to get answer of your 2nd point

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

In cases where an application doesn’t close connections properly, wait_timeout is an important parameter to tune and discard unused or idle connections to minimize the number of active connections to your MySQL server – and this will ultimately help to avoid the “Too many connections” error.

Threads_running is a valuable metric to monitor as it doesn’t count sleeping threads – it shows active and the amount of queries currently processing, while threads_connected status variables show all connected threads value including idle connections as well

Comment: @Rachit Patel I am thinking of using solaris to host mysql server. Any mysql configuration script would be helpful for handling huge traffic.

Comment: @Redone yes, you can change value of "max_connections" property to increase max connection. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html. and I don't have much clear idea about solaris or window server good for mysql.